# PDFTK, CODE128 and UTF-8

Tags: command-line, fonts, pdf, barcode, pdftk

I'm used to fill PDF forms from PHP using PDFTK. Recently, I was asked to insert a code-128 barcode in a PDF. To do so, I created a PDF with several text fields for human-readable entries plus a special text fields which text is render with a special font that represents code-128 symbols. This font can be found here: http://www.jtbarton.com/Barcodes/Code128.aspx. The only difference between human-readable and barcode fields is the font used to display the characters.

Up to this step, everything works fine. With Adobe Reader, I am able to copy-paste a prepared barcode into my special field, it renders just fine, this code can be scanned by barcode readers. A sample example is `Ñ000002HÓ` (`Ñ` is a starter, then is my data `000002`, the checksum `H` follows, and the whole ends with the stopper `Ó`).

Then I get into troubles when trying to fill the form with PDFTK. If I try to fill my special field with `Ñ000002HÓ` it only renders characters in the ASCII table (ie `000002H`) and displays some kind of squares instead of the expected barcode symboles for `Ñ` and `Ó`. More surprising, trying to fill human-readable fields with the exact same `Ñ000002HÓ` phrase works like a charm.

I verified both kind of fields receive the exact same characters sequence (including utf-8 encoding), I checked the font was well embedded in order to prevent display issues, I ensured the XFDF file is well-formed, etc.

Here a XFDF sample used to fill a PDF form with fields named 'human' and 'barcode'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
    <fields>
        <field name="human"><value>Ñ000002HÓ</value></field>
        <field name="barcode"><value>Ñ000002HÓ</value></field>
    </fields>
</xfdf>
```

I'm afraid I have no more ideas how to solve this issue. If you do, your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

At last, I found a solution. More precisely a workaround.

It seems PDFTK does not handle UTF-8 characters the right way with embed Identity-H fonts applied to form fields. In order to render the PDF file the right way, instead of *replacing* a field with a content, simply set this content as the *default value* of this field. This will make Acrobat handle the rendering process of the form field instead of delegating it to PDFTK.

To do so, simply add `need_appearances` to the PDFTK command line.

**NOTE** - The form field remains in the PDF created by PDFTK, meaning its content can then be modified by the user in Adobe Reader.

Comment: I believe you can run it once with the need_appearances option on, and get the desired result, and then run the result with the flatten option.